# How do I execute PHP code in a view?

Tags: views, plugins

There are myriad applications to need to execute specific PHP functions in Views rows. In many cases, making a custom Plugin is a better option. In other cases, it's better to use a Twig or custom token input filter.

Yet there are unique, specific use cases in which I need to simply talk to custom functions and the database in ways that are outside of a plugin.

I've reviewed this guide - https://enzo.weknowinc.com/how-include-php-code-drupal-8-views/ - but it did not work because Drupal console isn't functional for D9+, as it uses a later version of Symfony. All of the other resources I've found either 404 or cause errors due to being outdated.

Is there a way to accomplish the injection of PHP into views rows like D7?

Comment: You don't need Drupal console to create a module. The same can be done with Drush or on your own.

Comment: I can also do so manually, as I do often - but DC in this tutorial seems to auto-gen dependencies and use statements which i don't know off the top of my head. I'm looking to get a way to easily execute PHP in views. Right now I'm using php in blocks as an alternative, but I'd prefer this wouldn't be so difficult.

Comment: The Drupal 8/9/10 architecture is fundamentally different from Drupal 7 and there is no "easy" way to insert PHP anymore.  Use a plugin.  If you want to avoid plugins at all costs and do it like Drupal 7, then just use Drupal 7.  Drupal 8/9/10 are plugin-based; for better or worse, the future of Drupal is plugins.

Answer (score 2):

In the current Drush version you can build plugins to run PHP in Views with the following commands:

Field:

```
drush gen plugin:views:field
```

Style rows:

```
drush gen plugin:views:style
```

The first example is a direct replacement for a PHP field in earlier Drupal versions. The second command produces a nice example of a configurable plugin including a views twig template and its preprocess hook.